# using or storing username and password on register html

Tags: html, mysql, sql, authentication

I will really appreciate your concern of answering my first ever question here.

*This is a simple register html snippet for a user to input his/her username and password.*

```
<div class="container">

    <form class="form-register">
        <h1 class="form-register-heading text-muted">Fill Up!</h1>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Desired Username" required="" autofocus="">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Desired Password" required="">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit"  >  
            Register
        </button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Because  this is about registering a user on a site, then this is about storing the username and its info on a database for login checking that is to enable a user to log in on a site.

*The question is, How will I get the username and password data inputted by the user when the submit button is clicked by the user.That is for me to save this data into my database for further login checking if the username exist.
This is my sql function for registering the username and password on the database on a different file of course on an .sql file *

```
                 setuser(p_username text, p_password text)
```

So, How will I get the username and password from my html file when the submit button is clicked and link it onto my

> setuser(p_username text, p_password text)

from my sql file to again save it on my database ??  :DDD.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried googling "php mysql login tutorial"?

Comment: Can I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask